# How to sort data using MongoDB Compass by most recent Date

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to sort my Collections by date but cant figure this out. I tried passing in `{ date:1 }` in the Sort Field but doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

```
FILTER
          

PROJECT
          

SORT: {date: -1}

          

COLLATION
```

Results:

```
_id
:
6154f058c0f8e1001635db6f
longUrl
:
"https://"
shortUrl
:
"https://www.my.com/fuYYgGbCW"
urlCode
:
"fuYYgGbCW"
date
:
"Wed Sep 29 2021 23:01:44 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"
__v
:0

_id
:
6154e50bc0f8e1001635db63
longUrl
:
"https://www."
shortUrl
:
"https://www.my.com/AdT3Nt428"
urlCode
:
"AdT3Nt428"
date
:
"Wed Sep 29 2021 22:13:31 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"
__v
:
0
```

Comment: Id `date` a field of type `Date` or is a `String`?

Comment: Its a Date.....

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266